# python: elegant and code saving way to convert a list

Tags: python, performance, optimization, coding-style

First of all sorry for the easy question. I have a list (just an example)

```
points = [[663963.7405329756, 6178165.692240637],
 [664101.4213951868, 6177971.251818423],
 [664099.7474887948, 6177963.323432223],
 [664041.432877932, 6177903.295650704],
 [664031.8017317944, 6177895.797176996],
 [663963.7405329756, 6178165.692240637]]
```

I need to convert it to the following form

```
points = [(663963.7405329756, 6178165.692240637),
 (664101.4213951868, 6177971.251818423),
 (664099.7474887948, 6177963.323432223),
 (664041.432877932, 6177903.295650704),
 (664031.8017317944, 6177895.797176996),
 (663963.7405329756, 6178165.692240637)]
```

in order to create a `Polygon` object using [**shapely module**](http://toblerity.github.com/shapely/manual.html). I wrote several loops but really not elegant and time consuming. Do you know the best way to convert the first list into the second?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
converted = map(tuple, points) # Python 2
converted = list(map(tuple, points)) # or BlackBear's answer for Python 3
converted = [tuple(x) for x in points] # another variation of the same
```

Comment: The version using `map()` is the most efficient one, I think. And the shortest.

Comment: @PeterStahl Probably. It will also work on Python 3, but `converted` will not be a list, rather a generator. Sometimes it doesn't matter, in this case I also recommend using `map`.

Answer (score 2):

```
converted = [(a,b) for a,b in points]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
converted = [tuple(l) for l in points]
```

Compared to the solution given by @BlackBear, this works for sublists of arbitrary size.

Answer (score 1):

```
points = [tuple(x) for x in points]
```